# Notify when Polygon is loaded

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is there a way to be notified when a Google Maps polygon is drawn on screen?

I have editable polygons with several hundred points and it takes a while for them to display on the screen (about a second). I would like to add some kind of "loading" and then when the editable polygon is displayed, hide the notification.

I've tried the following, but since there is no `load` event on the polygon, it does not work.

```
            google.maps.event.addDomListener(gPolygon, 'load', function () {
               alert("addDomListener -- LOAD");
            });
            google.maps.event.addListener(gPolygon, 'load', function () {
               alert("addListener -- LOAD");
            });
```

My only other option is to set some kind of timer and try to guess when the polygon displays.

Comment: How are you drawing the polygon?

Technically if you're pushing points, you can use a promise or a callback, you wouldn't need an event.

Comment: Please share the code where you create your polygon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done tests to *really* long polygons (125000 points), using the following code:

```
> console.log(new Date().getTime());p.setMap(map);console.log(new Date().getTime())
1437051805161
1437051805229
< undefined
```

Since there is such a large difference in time (68 ms), as compared with a 1 ms difference with just two Dates, I think that `google.maps.Polygon.setMap` is synchronous. This means that it is possible just to fire the event as another block of code following the `setMap` command.

If you wanted, you could create a `prototype` function:

```
google.maps.Polygon.prototype.setMapListener(map, func, args){
  this.setMap(map);
  func(args);
}
```